# Display array from database into spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, spinner

I used an Array full of checkbox's to save data into one colum of a table. I want to display each item from this array in a spinner so it can be selectable.

I want to get the content from the column named KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE and display all the items saved in the array into a spinner. So what method can i put in the database? and how do i display it in a spinner? Here is my database file

```java
package com.example.com.facilitiesreviewapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

// creating the class
public class SQL {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Constants & Data
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // For logging:
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    // declaring and initializing data Primary Key Fields for both tables
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

    public static final String KEY_REVIEWROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_REVROWID = 0;

    //declaring and initializing other database Fields for both tables
    public static final String KEY_STATION_NAME = "StationName";
    public static final String KEY_STATION_TYPE = "StationType";
    public static final String KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE = "Facilities";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "Location";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String KEY_STATION_ID = "userId";

    public static final String KEY_REV_STATION_NAME = "revStationName";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "Date";
    public static final String KEY_REV_FACILITY = "revFacility";
    public static final String KEY_RATING = "Rating";
    public static final String KEY_COMMENT = "Comment";


    //Defining Field numbers for both tables
    public static final int COL_STATION_NAME = 2;
    public static final int COL_STATION_TYPE = 3;
    public static final int COL_FACILITIES_TYPE = 4;
    public static final int COL_LOCATION = 5;
    public static final int COL_EMAIL = 5;
    public static final int COL_STATION_ID = 1;

    public static final int COL_REV_STATION_NAME = 1;
    public static final int COL_DATE = 2;
    public static final int COL_REV_FACILITY = 3;
    public static final int COL_RATING = 4;
    public static final int COL_COMMENTS = 5;

    // declaring and initializing a string to get all fields from Establishment Table
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_STATION_NAME,
            KEY_STATION_TYPE, KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_STATION_ID};

    //declaring and initializing a string to get all fields from Review Table
    public static final String[] ALL_REV_KEYS = new String[]{KEY_REVIEWROWID, KEY_REV_STATION_NAME,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_REV_FACILITY, KEY_RATING, KEY_COMMENT};


    // declaring and initializing database name, and the two tables
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FacilitiesReview";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Stations";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "Review";

    // declaring and initializing a variable for tracking DB version if a new version of
    // the application changes the format.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // declaring and initializing a string to create the Establishment Table
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                    + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_STATION_NAME + " text,"
                    + KEY_STATION_TYPE + " text,"
                    + KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE + " text,"
                    + KEY_LOCATION + " text,"
                    + KEY_EMAIL + " text,"
                    + KEY_STATION_ID + " text"
                    + ");";

    // declaring and initializing a string to create the Review Table
    private static final String DATABASE2_CREATE_SQL =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE2
                    + " (" + KEY_REVIEWROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_REV_STATION_NAME + " text,"
                    + KEY_DATE + " text,"
                    + KEY_REV_FACILITY + " text,"
                    + KEY_RATING + " text,"
                    + KEY_COMMENT + " text"
                    + ");";

    // Creating the Context of application who uses us.
    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Public methods:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public SQL(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Opening the database connection.
    public SQL open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close the database connection.
    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Method for Adding a new establishment to the database.
    public long insertStation(String strStationID, String strName, String strStationType, String strFacilities, String strLocation,
                              String strEmail) {

        //assigning user input with database rows
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_STATION_ID, strStationID);
        values.put(KEY_STATION_NAME, strName);
        values.put(KEY_STATION_TYPE, strStationType);
        values.put(KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE, strFacilities);
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION, strLocation);
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, strEmail);


        // Inserting it into the database
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
    }

    // Method for Adding a new review to the database.
    public long insertReviewRow(String strRevStation, String strDate, String strRevFacility, Float strRating, String strComment) {

        //assigning user input with database rows
        ContentValues review_values = new ContentValues();
        review_values.put(KEY_REV_STATION_NAME, strRevStation);
        review_values.put(KEY_DATE, strDate);
        review_values.put(KEY_REV_FACILITY, strRevFacility);
        review_values.put(KEY_RATING, strRating);
        review_values.put(KEY_COMMENT, strComment);

        //Inserting it into the database
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, review_values);
    }

    /* method for Deleting a row from the database Establishment Table,
    by rowId (primary key/ Establishment)
    from the Establishment Table */
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }


    // Method for fetching all data in the database from the Establishment Table.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
                where, null, null, null, KEY_STATION_NAME, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Method for fetching all data in the database from the Review Table of the particular establishment
    // (by using passed establishment)
    public Cursor getAllReviewRows(String establishment) {
        //String where = null;
        String where = KEY_REV_STATION_NAME + " = '" + establishment + "'";
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE2, ALL_REV_KEYS,
                where, null, null, null, KEY_DATE, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Method for fetching data for a particular establishment (by using passed rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Private Helper Classes:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
     * Used to handle low-level database access.
     */
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        // Method for creating the Database
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE2_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        // Method for upgrading the database
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroying old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }


    public Cursor fetchStationsByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
            mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_STATION_ID, KEY_STATION_NAME, KEY_STATION_TYPE, KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE,KEY_LOCATION,KEY_EMAIL},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

        } else {
            mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_STATION_ID, KEY_STATION_NAME, KEY_STATION_TYPE, KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE,KEY_LOCATION,KEY_EMAIL},
                    KEY_STATION_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        }
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

}
```

Comment: just use [Simple]CursorAdapter, btw why are you calling moveToFirst before returning the Cursor?

Comment: pskink. those methods are to implemented on other parts not the one my question is for. Could u give me a hint or atleast a code for the database?

Comment: google for: android spinner cursor adapter example

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. But only problem is that the array of texts are all coming in one line and not each other on its own line. its showing like wifi,ramp,lifts.. instead of each word been in its own line

```html
public void loadtospinner() {

        Spinner spFacilityType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFacilityType);

        Cursor c = dbHelper.getAllRows();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_FACILITIES_TYPE));
            al.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1,
                al);

        spFacilityType.setAdapter(aa1);

        // closing database
        dbHelper.close();

    }
```